# Необычный парсинг авито

Tags: парсер, requests

Стоит задача спарсить новые обьявления в авито по заданной ссылке типа этой:[https://www.avito.ru/moskva/kvartiry/prodam-ASgBAgICAUSSA8YQ?f=ASgBAQICAkSSA8YQjvgO~LDjAgFA2sQNFIKfOg&footWalkingMetro=5](https://www.avito.ru/moskva/kvartiry/prodam-ASgBAgICAUSSA8YQ?f=ASgBAQICAkSSA8YQjvgO%7ELDjAgFA2sQNFIKfOg&footWalkingMetro=5)

Как обычно написал парсер через скачивание страницы, но оказалось существует возможность спарсить данные с страницы до того как они там появятся, как на этом видео:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BITocMltYvo&t=84s
Подскажите как такого можно добиться? В какую сторону гуглить? Я уже несколько дней мучаюсь.
Мне сказали смотреть в сторону хеширования, но честно говоря я не понимаю как с этим связанно хеширование. Пожалуйста обьясните дураку.

Comment: На видео реклама конкретного парсера (который может быть и не работает). И там речь о том, что веб-приложение кеширует на какое-то время выдачу и возникает небольшой лаг. А вообще парсить Авито неблагодарное занятие. Они с парсерами борются и через пару запросов покажут вам капчу. Поэтому вам надо либо научиться очень хорошо имитировать живого пользователя (и решать капчу в том числе), либо как-то хакнуть Авито (за это могут привлечь к ответственности). Можно ещё договориться с Авито о партнёрстве, но кажется это вообще не ваш вариант.

Comment: Да. Вы совершено правы, но всё же мне нужно добиться  его результатов. Я точно знаю что он не сотрудничает с авито, а обходить капчу или баны возможно. Вопрос в том как мне так же вытаскивать данные. Не подскажите?(

Comment: Сделать это можно через скачивание страницы. Скорее всего скачивать надо через реальный браузер с помощью [селениума](https://www.selenium.dev/), при этом тщательно маскируя этот селениум. Вероятно придётся завести пул адресов, с которых делать запросы. Ваша задача максимально точно имитировать реальных пользователей, для этого может даже понадобится автоматически водить мышкой по экрану.